# java.io.IOException: Access denied (H2 + Hibernate)

Tags: java, windows, permissions, administrator

Table size of more than 10,000 lines

Submit the request to read the last 100 lines of every 6 seconds
and one on the record

But sometimes there is an error

```
17:34:49,549 WARN SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 90031, SQLState: 90031
17:34:49,549 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Ошибка ввода/вывода: "java.io.IOException: Access denied";
"C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project/base.0b6276e133678305.1105.temp.db" IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: Access denied";
"C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project/base.0b6276e133678305.1105.temp.db";
    SQL statement: select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.broker as broker0_0_, this_.potential
    as potential0_0_, this_.quote as quote0_0_, this_.symbol as symbol0_0_,
    this_.timeQuote as timeQuote0_0_ from history this_ order by this_.id desc limit ? [90031-169]
```

All running with administrator privileges

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

The error is `java.io.IOException: Access denied`

This is unrelated to Hibernate and H2. For some reason, the Java process isn't allowed to create/modify the file. Possible causes:

1. The parent folder doesn't exist
2. You're not allowed to create/read/modify files in that folder. Unlike on Unix, the `Administrator` can't do everything on Windows. You have to take over the folder first if it doesn't belong to you. In this case, the folder probably belongs to the user `name` and if he didn't allow access to `Administrator`, then you get an error.
3. The file name contains illegal characters. Unlikely in your case.
4. There is a directory `C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project/base.0b6276e133678305.1105.temp.db`.

Comment: Maybe `C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project/base.0b6276e133678305.1105.temp.db` is a directory.

Comment: Try to create a file in that folder by calling `new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/name/Documents/NetBeansProjects/project/test.txt")`. Does that work?

Comment: How do you create the file names?

Comment: in the sense?
database itself creates them

Comment: What kind of query creates these files? Did you check the documentation whether you can move the path where the files are created? Did you try to create the database in `C:\bugtest\` just to see whether the error goes away?